# How to remove duplicated elements on hashtable that were added with foreach in powershell script?

Tags: powershell, dictionary, foreach, hashtable

I have an array which has duplicated elements. I wish to use a dictionary for removing the duplicated elements. This is my code block :

```
$dictionary = [ordered]@{}
ForEach ($item In $pkg){
    $dictionary.Add($item.Id, $item.Version)
}
```

The dictionary still has duplicated elements, but when adding to it like this:

```
$dictionary.Add("NHibernate", "4.0.4.4000")

$dictionary.Add("NHibernate", "4.0.4.4000")
```

it is not allowed. What am I doing wrong?

The array is a result of doing this

```
@( Get-Project -All | ? { $_.ProjectName } | % { Get-Package -ProjectName $_.ProjectName } ) | ? { $_.LicenseUrl } | ...
```

in the package manager console in Visual Studio.

Comment: Could you provide some example data please? If I got you right you could use `Select-Object -Unique` to remove duplicates.

Comment: I am working on package manager console on visual studio. I tried _Select-Object -Unique_ but it is not working. @Olaf , its my example of script `@( Get-Project -All | ? { $_.ProjectName } | %  {
    Get-Package -ProjectName $_.ProjectName } ) | ? { $_.LicenseUrl } | ...`

Comment: You should update your question instead of adding information as comment, please. With sample data I meant the content of your variable  `$pkg`

Comment: As some of us do not have access to a Visual Studio installation and no one of us has access to your environment it would be helpful or actually necessary that you provide some sample data ... at least 3 or 4 rows of your variable `$pkg`  ... cleaned from sensitive information of course. You might read again [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are right about  imperfect knowledge . I did my best. I will try another time.Thans for advice. @Olaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow identical keys to overwrite the value already in the dictionary (last item 'wins'), use this syntax:

```
foreach ($item In $pkg){
    $dictionary[$item.Id] = $item.Version
}
```

If you want to skip items with the same keys, use this:

```
foreach ($item In $pkg) {
    if (!($dictionary.Contains($item.Id))) {
        $dictionary.Add($item.Id, $item.Version)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to overwrite your `values` of already existing `keys`, you could check if the `key` already exists before adding it to the `hashtable` (again):

```
ForEach ($item In $pkg){
    if( -not $dictionary.Item($item.Id)){
        $dictionary.Add($item.Id, $item.Version)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried on my code but it is not working. @TobyU thanks.